# UIViewController Functions Calling Hierarchy

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have been asked this question in many interviews for iPhone Developer position. I have googled it but couldnt find a satisfactory answer.
The Question is

" what is the order of calling for the UIViewController functions "
Some of functions that i know are

1. loadview
2. viewDidLoad
3. viewWillAppear
4. viewDidUnload

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It goes something like this:

```
-loadView,
-viewDidLoad,
-viewWillAppear,
-viewDidAppear,
-viewWillDisappear,
-viewDidDisappear,
-viewDidUnload
```

Comment: Is that really a hierarchy though? Isn't it the function order when a view is loaded / unloaded?

Comment: @Rudiger Try to answer the question and Get rewarded by an UpVote. Its better not to find errors in the Query.

Comment: @Jacob, I just did it Boy :) by the way u already have impressive profile with 18k points, an upvote make much difference to them :).

Comment: @T.A I answered the question as it was written. You asked originally for a hierarchy and what you wanted was an order. I'm not complaining that you changed it, but don't blame me for not giving the answer you wanted. I even deleted my answer when you amended it

Comment: @Rudiger
Ok dude, i apologize my mistake . I take my words back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:

```
 NSLog(@"%@::%@", [[self class] description], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

in every function of the above and see how things going in the log window...